# On hover change text color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change text color on hover but the color stays the same as it were before.

I'm using script to add class named `.show` to change background while scrolling, it works, also the hovering elements works but the `color` CSS element fails to change.

Here are some attempts of adding `:hover` to change the color after the user scroll downwards.
 I would like the color to change from grey to black once the user scroll downwards.

```
.navigation-bar li a {
  display: inline;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: 0.2s ease color;
  position:relative;
}
.show:hover .navigation-bar li a {
  color: black;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.show {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.show:hover{
  background-color: #ebe4dd;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div class="bg transition">

<div id="navigation-container">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#title">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section1">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Get in Touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/MWYoQaO)

How can I change the color on hovering once the user have scrolled down?

Comment: In CodePen, I can see .show css class attribute. I have changed the .show:hover selector to this as a simple fix for now  ul >li a:hover and it works. So fix you css selector as suggested  to ul >li a:hover

Comment: i just add !important to your .show class and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong order elements of classes here:

```css
.show:hover .navigation-bar li a {
  color: black;
}
```

This one would be correct:

```css
.navigation-bar .show:hover li a {
  color: black;  
}
```

Comment: This answer does not contain sufficient detail and feels more like a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You must define a css rule when the `.show` is added.

add this line in your CSS :

```
.show  div#navigation-container ul li a{
  color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fork of the codepen listed in the question to show your css working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get you right or not, but this is changing the navbar's text color on hover

```
$('#navigation-container').hover(function() {
    $('li > a').css({'color':'black'});
  }, function() {
    $('li > a').css({'color':'grey'});
  });
```